# Keytool using a HERE document

Tags: parameters, keytool

How can I pass the answers to the keytool command?

```
  keytool -keystore etc/mykeystore -alias myAlias -genkey -keyalg RSA -keypass mySecretPassword -storepass mySecretPassword
```

I read that I have to use a HERE document but I don't understand how its syntax works.
Any help?

Thank you,
Daniel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I just found out the answer to my question. At least the following works.

```
[root@myserver ~]# cat scriptkeytool 
keytool -keystore /etc/whatever/keystore -alias myalias -genkey -keyalg RSA -keypass mykeypass -storepass mystorepass <<EOF
My Name and Last Name
IT
CONTOSO
Redmon
California
US
yes
EOF
```